# How to define a Javascript class static method by using a function defined elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Javascript class (env: node.js v12 or above) defined like this:

```
module.exports = class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {

// ...

  static async someMethod() {
    const result = await this.exampleSuperMethod()
  return result
}

// ...

}
```

I'm extending `SomeOtherClass`, which defines a static method called `exampleSuperMethod`, which is used in my `someMethod` as described above.

Now, I'd like to define the `someMethod` method by using a function defined somewhere else. This is needed because the function is something generic and I'd like not to repeat the same code in my classes. More over, defining the function in an external module, I can test it once only and reuse everywhere my *shared and tested* code.

To achieve this, I'd like to have a function defined like the following:

```
const myMethod = (MainClass) => async () => {
  const result = await MainClass.exampleSuperMethod({
    // do something
  })
  return result
}

module.exports = myMethod
```

In this function, I'm allowing the dependency injection of `MainClass` (needed to reach the `exampleSuperMethod`), by exporting a high order function which defines my needed function with a closure.
With a class defined like this, I'll be able to mock simply the "main" `SomeOtherClass` and pass in to the high order function this mock, which exposes the `exampleSuperMethod`. In the real usage, my idea is to inject the `this` element and get back the function ready to be plugged in my class as a static method. But I'm not sure how to achieve this last point.

My main class could become something like the following:

```
const useMyMethod = require('./path-to-file/my-method.js')

module.exports = class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {

// ...

  // how to replace the following to use the 
  // function received by the call to 
  // useMyMethod(this) ?
  //
  static async someMethod() {
    const result = await this.exampleSuperMethod()
  return result
}

// ...

}
```

I'm wondering how to replace the initial definition of `someMethod` with the function returned by `useMyMethod(this)`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you can simply call `static async someMethod(){ return await useMyMethod(this); }`

Comment: Thank you @palaѕн. The correct code should be:
`static async someMethod() { return await useMyMethod(this)(); }`
(the actual function call was missing)
But I was trying to understand if there's a way to inject the function in the class without actually calling it and returning its returned value.